# Fastest Way to Add a Column to an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to dynamically add some columns (and remove others) from an html table. As there is no html `<tr>` analog for columns, the best way I can think of is to loop over the rows and add `<td>`'s with javascript. This is slow though as it causes a lot of browser reflows (I have a lot of rows to modify), and I am wondering if any javascript/css wizards know a trick to make this faster.

Comment: How many columns do you need to add? Is it an option to have them there to start with but hidden? Give each column a unique class-name and set that class to visible to display.

Comment: @Chris: I was just about to suggest the same thing.

Comment: Similar to this, you can create your new columns row by row but with a hidden class. Then at the end just make the class visible.

Comment: @Chris: If I added the new td's row by row, but the td's were display: none, would each addition prevent a reflow?

Comment: @Joda Maki, there would be one giant reflow at the end when you set the class to visible.

Comment: So there are 2 ways you can do it - so that it only causes one reflow and not one per row.
1) doing it how Chris said.   2) use JavaScript to constuct the HTML for the new table into a single string, and then replace the current table with the new table in a single call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a brand new `table` DOM element and copy the existing table's children to it, adding your new `<td>`s in the right places, then, when you are all done constructing the DOM tree for the new table, remove the old table and put the new one in place. This will cause only one reflow.

Comment: nice thinking, what is the fastest way to copy the existing table's children to the new table? I must use native js, no jquery or something. Would it just be to get the DOM ref of the tbody, then remove it from old table, and append it to the new?

Comment: @Joda - if you remove the tbody from the old table you'll cause a reflow. I'd experiment (don't know offhand) if you could add it to the new table w/o removing it from the old (2 parents?), or clone it if that's not possible. I'd probably create new nodes for table, thead, tbody, tfoot, and loop over the `tr`s copying/cloning/re-parenting them and adding the new `td`s as I did that. Haven't tried it of course, but that's my thought.